# How do I add more than one Leaflet Toolbar

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to have multiple toolbars on a Leaflet map using [the Leaflet.Toolbar library](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.toolbar)

Simplified code looks like this:

```
var actions = [
    L.Toolbar2.Action.extend({
        options: { toolbarIcon: { html: 'a', tooltip: 'Zoom to all' } },
        addHooks: function () { console.log('a') }
    }),
    L.Toolbar2.Action.extend({
        options: { toolbarIcon: { html: 'p', tooltip: 'Zoom to all' } },
        addHooks: function () { console.log('p') }
    }),
    L.Toolbar2.Action.extend({
        options: { toolbarIcon: { html: 'e', tooltip: 'Zoom to all' } },
        addHooks: function () { console.log('e') }
    }),
];

var toolbar1 = new L.Toolbar2.Control({ actions: actions, position: 'topright' });

toolbar1.addTo(this.map);

var toolbar2 = new L.Toolbar2.Control({ actions: actions, position: 'topleft' });

toolbar2.addTo(this.map);
```

However this seems to only attach the last toolbar - the ones that got appended previously are lot.

Is it possible to have more than one toolbar, and how?

Comment: I don't really undestand the docu but try it with `L.Toolbar.Control` for the first one and use `L.Toolbar2.Control` for the second one

Comment: @FalkeDesign - thanks but nope - ```TypeError: L.Toolbar is undefined```